# SQL Server Use result from one query and use it in another query.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am pretty new at sql.

I want the following:

```
SELECT transID from tblTrans WHERE transDesc = @TransDesc

UPDATE tblData SET Complete = GETDATE() WHERE transNo = (Result from First Query)
```

How do I put the result of the first query into the 2nd query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tblData SET Complete = GETDATE() WHERE transNo IN  (SELECT transID from tblTrans WHERE transDesc = @TransDesc)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this. The first follows your original, and assumes there is only one transID:

```
DECLARE @transID int

SELECT @transID = transID from tblTrans WHERE transDesc = @TransDesc

UPDATE tblData SET Complete = GETDATE() WHERE transNo = @transID
```

The second is neater, as it puts the entire update into a single command:

```
UPDATE tblData SET Complete = GETDATE()
    FROM tblTrans t
    WHERE t.transID = tblData.transNo
      AND t.transDesc = @TransDesc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
UPDATE tblData SET Complete = GETDATE()
    WHERE transNo IN (SELECT transID from tblTrans WHERE transDesc = @TransDesc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblData 
SET Complete = GETDATE() 
WHERE transNo IN
    (SELECT transID 
     from tblTrans 
    WHERE transDesc = @TransDesc)
```